# Passing down injected services to other objects

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, blazor

I'm not a professionally trained developer, so bear with me please. As I'm very interested in development and doing it as a hobby, I'm sometimes tasked to code little tools at work.

Now, I'm tackling a larger project using Blazor and I'm not sure how to handle a probably common task with dependency injection. But I guess the question is not really Blazor specific but more of a DI related question.

Let's say I have following classes (that's the way I'm basically doing it now):

```
public class MyServiceA{
    public void DoSomething();
}
public class MyServiceB{
    public void DoSomethingElse();
}
public class MyServiceC{
    public void DoSomethingTotallyDifferent();
}

public class MyClassA{
    public MyClassB MyClassB {get;set;}
    public MyServiceA MyServiceA {get;set;}


    public MyClassA (MyServiceA myServiceA, MyServiceB myServiceB, MyServiceC mySerivceC){
        MyServiceA = myServiceA;
        MyClassB = new MyClassB(myServiceB, myServiceC);
    }

    public void SomeFunction(){
        MyServiceA.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class MyClassB{
    public MyClassC MyClassC{get;set;}
    public MyServiceB MyServiceB{get;set;}

    public MyClassB(MyServiceB myServiceB, MyServiceC myServiceC){
        MyServiceB = myServiceB;
        MyClassC = new MyClassC(myServiceC)
    }
}

public class MyClassC{
    public MyServiceC MyServiceC{get;set;}

    public MyClassC(MyServiceC myServiceC){
        MyServiceC = myServiceC;
    }
}
```

My question is if, while using DI, it is the expected pattern to inject all the necessary services for the complex object hierarchy in `MyClassA` and pass them along to the other classes using constructor parameters, even if a class down the line doesn't care about some services? (e.g. `MyClassB` doesn't care about `MyServiceC` but needs it to pass it down to `MyClassC`)

This could lead to constructors with a lot of parameters, even though the class doesn't necessarily need them.

I was thinking maybe I could do something like creating a DependencyContainer

```
public class DependencyContainer{
    public MyServiceA MyServiceA{get;set;}
    public MyServiceB MyServiceB{get;set;}
    public MyServiceC MyServiceC{get;set;}

    public DependencyContainer(MyServiceA myServiceA, MySerivceB myServiceB, MyServiceC myServiceC)
    {
        MyServiceA = myServiceA;
        MyServiceB = myServiceB;
        MyServiceC = myServiceC;
    }
}

public Class MyClassA{
    DependencyContainer Container{get;set;}
    MyClassB MyClassB {get;set;}
    public MyClassA(DependencyContainer container){
        Container = container;
        MyClassB = new MyClassB(container);
    }
    public void SomeFunction(){
        Container.MyServiceA.DoSomething();
    }
}
//etc...
```

This way, I would have access to all services and would only need to pass down a single constructor parameter.

I would love to know the correct way to do this, even if only for my own curiosity :-)

Comment: Abstractions aside, ClassB should be explicitly injected into ClassA. ClassC should be explicitly injected into ClassB. Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

Comment: I left the abstractions aside on purpose for simplicities sake. 

What if ClassB has a constructor parameter, for example, int Id which it gets from ClassA depending an user input. I will not be able to inject it explicitly?

Comment: Then that is  trying to inject run-time data. Reference [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for those links. The articles are super interesting. I'll definitely reconsider my architecture

Comment: My philosophy is this:   when you create a class In Blazor think Service, Component or Data Class.  The only real exceptions are utility class - normally static. Then the only decision is scope.  There's a little used component called `OwningComponentClass` that creates it's own scoped DI container for custom component situations,  Your classes look like DI services to me.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis thanks for the blazor related tip with the OwningComponentClass. I didn't know about that but it seems to be really useful.